# Loop in LaTeX is not working

Tags: macros, loops

I wrote this command:

```
\newcounter{Lec}

\newcommand{\MakeLecture}[2]{
    \setcounter{Lec}{#1}
        \loop
    \input{\code/Lecture Slides/Chapter0\theLec}
    \addtocounter{Lec}{1}\ifnum\value{Lec}<#2   \repeat
 }
```

And then I use it after `\begin{document}` to input multiple files, similar to this code,

```
\begin{document}

\MakeLecture{1}{4}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the file only inputs the first file (Chapter01), while in the above code it should input three files, Chapter01, Chapter02, and Chapter03. So what is wrong with this loop?

Comment: Do you mean it worked for you?

Comment: It works only if you don't use a `\loop...\repeat` inside the chapter files, and if you don't change the `Lec` counter in there.  Do you do one of these in the `Chapter01` file?

Comment: no I don't do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code worked for me with some minimal files, but `\input`ting files in the middle of a loop might go wrong, as Phelype pointed out in his comment.

I'd use a somewhat safer approach by defining a macro in the loop which collects the various `\input` and calling this macro when the loop is done. I've changed your definition such that `\MakeLecture{1}{4}` inserts the files from 1 to 4 (and not 3 as in your case) because it sounds more reasonable to me but you can just delete the line `\advance\count@\m@ne` if you don't want that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MakeLecture}[2]{%
   \count@=#1
   \advance\count@\m@ne
   \def\@inputmyfiles{}%
   \loop\ifnum\count@<#2
      \advance\count@\@ne
      \edef\@inputmyfiles{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@inputmyfiles}\noexpand\input{Chapter0\the\count@}}%
   \repeat
   \show\@inputmyfiles % ---> just for testing, delete this in real use
   \@inputmyfiles
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\MakeLecture{2}{5}
\end{document}
```

The `\show` command returns

```
> \@inputmyfiles=macro:
->\input {Chapter02}\input {Chapter03}\input {Chapter04}\input {Chapter05}.
```

Comment: Is there a document that can I read to learn these commands?

Comment: @Diana Which ones in particular? The counter manipulations are just basic TeX stuff, so as reference either the TeXbook of TeX by Topic. The tricky thing is `\unexpanded\expandafter{`. `\unexpanded` is documented in the e-TeX manual, and it works like a token register, so again look at the TeX book.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the Tex book

Answer (score 6):

A one-liner with `expl3` (can be nested):

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \MakeLecture { O{1} m }
  { \int_step_inline:nnn {#1} {#2} { \input {Chapter0##1} } }
  % { \int_step_inline:nnn {#1} {#2} { \input {\code/Lecture~Slides/Chapter0##1} } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\MakeLecture{4} % same as \MakeLecture[1]{4}
```

Comment: Is there a document that can I read to learn these commands?

Comment: @Diana `\int_step_inline:nnn` is documented in [`interface3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). `\int_step_inline:nnn { <begin> } { <end> } { <code> }` loops from `<begin>` to `<end>` in increments of 1, and executes `<code>` at each iteration.  Inside `<code>` the loop index is available as `#1` (`##1` in this answer, as it's inside a definition).

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have your `\input`-files available with all of the examples below I wrapped `\input`-commands into `\message`-commands which— rather than having carried it out— display the corresponding `\input`-command on the terminal/in the window of the shell from which latex is called for compiling. (`^^J` denotes beginning a new line on the terminal.)

First I do this with your code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Lec}

\newcommand{\MakeLecture}[2]{%
    \setcounter{Lec}{#1}%
        \loop
    \message{^^J\string\input{\string\code/Lecture Slides/Chapter0\theLec}^^J}%
    \addtocounter{Lec}{1}\ifnum\value{Lec}<#2   \repeat
 }

\begin{document}

\MakeLecture{1}{4}

\end{document}
```

It works out.
With (the slightly modified variation of) your code, too, I get the output displayed at the bottom of this answer.

**So my answer to your question "So what is wrong with this loop?" is:**

**It seems there is nothing wrong with your loop in principle.**

**But the macro `\loop` has some—eh— peculiarities** which are revealed by `\show\loop`—`\show\loop` displays the definition of `\loop` on the terminal:

```
\loop=\long macro:
#1\repeat ->\def \iterate {#1\relax \expandafter \iterate \fi }\iterate \let \i
terate \relax .
```

1. `\loop` processes an argument which is delimited by the token `\repeat`.
2. `\loop` defines a macro `\iterate` from that argument and **relies on that macro `\iterate` not being redefined until the loop terminates.** When the loop terminates, `\iterate` is let equal to `\relax` which is a no-op-control-sequence which is not removed during macro-expansion in TeX's gullet but which makes it into TeX's stomach and is removed there.

Peculiarity 1 implies:

- Nesting `\loop`...`\repeat` directly does not work out due to wrong delimiter-matching.

Peculiarity 2 implies:

- Nesting `\loop`...`\repeat` directly may not work out because the unmatched `\if...`-condition within `\loop..\repeat` may cause wrong `\if...\fi`-matching within the definition-text of `\iterate`
- Nesting macros inside `\loop..\repeat` which at some stage expand to `\loop`  does not work out either:

  Outer instances of `\loop` rely on `\iterate` not being redefined until the loop is terminated.
  Inner instances of `\loop` redefine `\iterate` permanently within the current scope/group. E.g., when inner loops terminate, they set `\iterate` to `\relax` which breaks consecutive iterating of outer instances of `\loop`.

I suppose that the files being `\input` contain a call to a macro whose expansion at some stage yields another instance of the `\loop`-macro which breaks your loop. Probably some package in use brings along such a macro without you knowing it.

(By the way: The defining of `\iterate` from the arguments the user provides to the `\loop`-macro is a source for another issue: If the arguments provided by the user are to define (temporary) macros which process arguments, with these arguments hashes (`#`) need to be doubled although at first glimpse at a `\loop..\repeat`-construct you cannot see the nesting of macro-definitions inside macro-definitions.)

**So what can be done?**

If you like it weird, then you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Lec}

\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\AfterMyDelimiter{%
  \long\def\AfterMyDelimiter#1#2\MyDelimiter{#2#1\MyDelimiter}%
}%
\newcommand*\MyDelimiter{}%

\newcommand{\MakeLecture}[2]{%
  \setcounter{Lec}{#1}%
  \loop
    \AfterMyDelimiter{%
      \message{^^J\string\input{\string\code/Lecture Slides/Chapter0\theLec}^^J}%
      \addtocounter{Lec}{1}%
    }%
  \ifnum#2>\value{Lec}%
    \addtocounter{Lec}{1}%
  \repeat
  \setcounter{Lec}{#1}%
  \MyDelimiter
}

\begin{document}

\MakeLecture{1}{3}

\end{document}
```

Tail-recursion, perhaps, is a little bit more straightforward:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\MakeLecture}[2]{%
  \message{^^J\string\input{\string\code/Lecture Slides/Chapter0#1}^^J}%  
  \csname @\ifnum#1<#2 firstofon\else gobbl\fi e\endcsname
  {\expandafter\MakeLecture\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}}%
}%

\begin{document}

\MakeLecture{1}{3}

\end{document}
```

If for some reason you wish to accumulate `\input`-calls first:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\MakeLecture}[2]{\MakeLectureLoop{#1}{#2}{}}%

\newcommand\MakeLectureLoop[3]{%
  \csname @\ifnum#1<#2 firstofone\else secondoftwo\fi\endcsname
  {\expandafter\MakeLectureLoop\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}}%
  {#3\message{^^J\string\input{\string\code/Lecture Slides/Chapter0#1}^^J}}%
}%

\begin{document}

\MakeLecture{1}{3}

\end{document}
```

When saving either of the examples above as `test.tex` and compiling it, the shell on my system displays:

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux) 
\input{\code/Lecture Slides/Chapter01}

\input{\code/Lecture Slides/Chapter02}

\input{\code/Lecture Slides/Chapter03}
(./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```